# how to prevent reporting services from caching excel/pdf reports

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SQL Server 2008 R2 
SSRS

Currently we have users that generate PDF/Excel versions of some SSRS reports from a link. (The end user doesn't see the URL)

We're noticing that if they generate a report(click the link), recalculate the values and click the link again, they're getting a cached version of the report.

Is there a way to prevent caching reports through SSRS? or is this an IE problem? (Can we force no caching for certain sites in their browser settings?)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've figured this one out already but I add a nullable unique parameter to make the browser realize that it is downloading a different resource. This way the url is always different, so the browser will always request from the server.

For example:

> http:///ReportServer?/MyReports/MyReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL&CompanyId=1&**unique=123456789**

What you use to generate the unique number is up to you. It could be something like a current date (like `DateTime.Now.Ticks`) or a generated random number as long as it is unique across requests.

FYI: Some have also had success with adding `rs:ClearSession=true` to the query string though this did not work for me...

Note: There should be a way to set the `Cache-Control` http header to `No-Cache` for SSRS. If anyone knows how to do this, please post...